# Unable to build a Flutter app for iPhone 4s Simulator in Xcode

Tags: xcode, google-cloud-firestore, flutter

I am getting the following exception when trying to deploy to an iPhone 4s in X-code. I would like to build the app in X-code so I can troubleshoot why the Flutter app is crashing on iPhone 4s devices running iOS 9.3.

```
Showing Recent Issues

Build target BoringSSL of project Pods with configuration Debug


Build target GTMSessionFetcher of project Pods with configuration Debug


Build target GoogleToolboxForMac of project Pods with configuration Debug


Build target leveldb-library of project Pods with configuration Debug


Build target Protobuf of project Pods with configuration Debug


Build target gRPC-RxLibrary of project Pods with configuration Debug


Build target nanopb of project Pods with configuration Debug


Build target gRPC-gRPCCertificates of project Pods with configuration Debug


Build target path_provider of project Pods with configuration Debug


Build target FirebaseCore of project Pods with configuration Debug


Build target shared_preferences of project Pods with configuration Debug


Build target url_launcher of project Pods with configuration Debug


Build target firebase_core of project Pods with configuration Debug


Build target FirebaseAuth of project Pods with configuration Debug


Build target FirebaseDatabase of project Pods with configuration Debug


Build target gRPC-Core of project Pods with configuration Debug


Build target gRPC of project Pods with configuration Debug


Build target gRPC-ProtoRPC of project Pods with configuration Debug


Build target FirebaseFirestore of project Pods with configuration Debug


Build target cloud_firestore of project Pods with configuration Debug


Build target Pods-Runner of project Pods with configuration Debug


Build target Runner of project Runner with configuration Debug

Ld /Users/darrankelinske/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-blzfibiocdhyedgaqedybuojiikn/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/Runner normal i386
    cd /Users/darrankelinske/source/flutter/austin-feeds-me-flutter/ios
    export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=8.0
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch i386 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator11.4.sdk -L/Users/darrankelinske/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-blzfibiocdhyedgaqedybuojiikn/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -L/Users/darrankelinske/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-blzfibiocdhyedgaqedybuojiikn/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/BoringSSL -L/Users/darrankelinske/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-blzfibiocdhyedgaqedybuojiikn/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/FirebaseAuth -L/Users/darrankelinske/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-blzfibiocdhyedgaqedybuojiikn/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/FirebaseCore -L/Users/darrankelinske/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-blzfibiocdhyedgaqedybuojiikn/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/FirebaseDatabase -L/Users/darrankelinske/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-blzfibiocdhyedgaqedybuojiikn/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/FirebaseFirestore -L/Users/darrankelinske/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-blzfibiocdhyedgaqedybuojiikn/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/GTMSessionFetcher -L/Users/darrankelinske/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-blzfibiocdhyedgaqedybuojiikn/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleToolboxForMac -L/Users/darrankelinske/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-blzfibiocdhyedgaqedybuojiikn/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Protobuf -L/Users/darrankelinske/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-blzfibiocdhyedgaqedybuojiikn/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/cloud_firestore -L/Users/darrankelinske/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-blzfibiocdhyedgaqedybuojiikn/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/firebase_core -L/Users/darrankelinske/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-blzfibiocdhyedgaqedybuojiikn/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/gRPC -L/Users/darrankelinske/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-blzfibiocdhyedgaqedybuojiikn/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/gRPC-Core -L/Users/darrankelinske/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-blzfibiocdhyedgaqedybuojiikn/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/gRPC-ProtoRPC -L/Users/darrankelinske/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-blzfibiocdhyedgaqedybuojiikn/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/gRPC-RxLibrary -L/Users/darrankelinske/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-blzfibiocdhyedgaqedybuojiikn/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/leveldb-library -L/Users/darrankelinske/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-blzfibiocdhyedgaqedybuojiikn/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/nanopb -L/Users/darrankelinske/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-blzfibiocdhyedgaqedybuojiikn/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/path_provider -L/Users/darrankelinske/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-blzfibiocdhyedgaqedybuojiikn/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/shared_preferences -L/Users/darrankelinske/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-blzfibiocdhyedgaqedybuojiikn/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/url_launcher -L/Users/darrankelinske/source/flutter/austin-feeds-me-flutter/ios/Flutter -F/Users/darrankelinske/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-blzfibiocdhyedgaqedybuojiikn/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/darrankelinske/source/flutter/austin-feeds-me-flutter/ios/Pods/FirebaseAnalytics/Frameworks -F/Users/darrankelinske/source/flutter/austin-feeds-me-flutter/ios/Pods/FirebaseInstanceID/Frameworks -F/Users/darrankelinske/source/flutter/austin-feeds-me-flutter/ios/Pods/../.symlinks/flutter/ios -F/Users/darrankelinske/source/flutter/austin-feeds-me-flutter/ios/Flutter -filelist /Users/darrankelinske/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-blzfibiocdhyedgaqedybuojiikn/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.build/Objects-normal/i386/Runner.LinkFileList -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @loader_path/Frameworks -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @loader_path/Frameworks -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -mios-simulator-version-min=8.0 -dead_strip -Xlinker -object_path_lto -Xlinker /Users/darrankelinske/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-blzfibiocdhyedgaqedybuojiikn/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.build/Objects-normal/i386/Runner_lto.o -Xlinker -export_dynamic -Xlinker -no_deduplicate -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -ObjC -lBoringSSL -lFirebaseAuth -lFirebaseCore -lFirebaseDatabase -lFirebaseFirestore -lGTMSessionFetcher -lGoogleToolboxForMac -lProtobuf -lc++ -lcloud_firestore -lfirebase_core -lgRPC -lgRPC-Core -lgRPC-ProtoRPC -lgRPC-RxLibrary -licucore -lleveldb-library -lnanopb -lpath_provider -lshared_preferences -lsqlite3 -lurl_launcher -lz -framework CFNetwork -framework FirebaseAnalytics -framework FirebaseCoreDiagnostics -framework FirebaseInstanceID -framework FirebaseNanoPB -framework Flutter -framework Foundation -framework MobileCoreServices -framework Security -framework StoreKit -framework SystemConfiguration -ObjC -lBoringSSL -lFirebaseAuth -lFirebaseCore -lFirebaseDatabase -lFirebaseFirestore -lGTMSessionFetcher -lGoogleToolboxForMac -lProtobuf -lc++ -lcloud_firestore -lfirebase_core -lgRPC -lgRPC-Core -lgRPC-ProtoRPC -lgRPC-RxLibrary -licucore -lleveldb-library -lnanopb -lpath_provider -lshared_preferences -lsqlite3 -lurl_launcher -lz -framework CFNetwork -framework FirebaseAnalytics -framework FirebaseCoreDiagnostics -framework FirebaseInstanceID -framework FirebaseNanoPB -framework Flutter -framework Foundation -framework MobileCoreServices -framework Security -framework StoreKit -framework SystemConfiguration -Xlinker -sectcreate -Xlinker __TEXT -Xlinker __entitlements -Xlinker /Users/darrankelinske/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-blzfibiocdhyedgaqedybuojiikn/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.build/Runner.app-Simulated.xcent -framework Flutter -framework App -lPods-Runner -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/darrankelinske/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-blzfibiocdhyedgaqedybuojiikn/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.build/Objects-normal/i386/Runner_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/darrankelinske/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-blzfibiocdhyedgaqedybuojiikn/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/Runner

ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/darrankelinske/Downloads/flutter/bin/cache/artifacts/engine/ios/Flutter.framework/Flutter, missing required architecture i386 in file /Users/darrankelinske/Downloads/flutter/bin/cache/artifacts/engine/ios/Flutter.framework/Flutter (3 slices)
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_FlutterMethodNotImplemented", referenced from:
      -[FLTCloudFirestorePlugin handleMethodCall:result:] in libcloud_firestore.a(CloudFirestorePlugin.o)
      -[FLTFirebaseCorePlugin handleMethodCall:result:] in libfirebase_core.a(FirebaseCorePlugin.o)
      ___47+[FLTPathProviderPlugin registerWithRegistrar:]_block_invoke in libpath_provider.a(PathProviderPlugin.o)
      ___52+[FLTSharedPreferencesPlugin registerWithRegistrar:]_block_invoke in libshared_preferences.a(SharedPreferencesPlugin.o)
      -[FLTUrlLauncherPlugin handleMethodCall:result:] in liburl_launcher.a(UrlLauncherPlugin.o)
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_FlutterStandardWriter", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_FirestoreWriter in libcloud_firestore.a(CloudFirestorePlugin.o)
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_FlutterStandardReader", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_FirestoreReader in libcloud_firestore.a(CloudFirestorePlugin.o)
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_FlutterStandardReaderWriter", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_FirestoreReaderWriter in libcloud_firestore.a(CloudFirestorePlugin.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FlutterStandardReaderWriter", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_FirestoreReaderWriter in libcloud_firestore.a(CloudFirestorePlugin.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FlutterStandardWriter", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_FirestoreWriter in libcloud_firestore.a(CloudFirestorePlugin.o)
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_FlutterAppDelegate", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_AppDelegate in AppDelegate.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FlutterStandardReader", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_FirestoreReader in libcloud_firestore.a(CloudFirestorePlugin.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FlutterMethodChannel", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libcloud_firestore.a(CloudFirestorePlugin.o)
      objc-class-ref in libfirebase_core.a(FirebaseCorePlugin.o)
      objc-class-ref in libpath_provider.a(PathProviderPlugin.o)
      objc-class-ref in libshared_preferences.a(SharedPreferencesPlugin.o)
      objc-class-ref in liburl_launcher.a(UrlLauncherPlugin.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FlutterError", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libcloud_firestore.a(CloudFirestorePlugin.o)
      objc-class-ref in liburl_launcher.a(UrlLauncherPlugin.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FlutterAppDelegate", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_AppDelegate in AppDelegate.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FlutterStandardMethodCodec", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libcloud_firestore.a(CloudFirestorePlugin.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)



Build failed    7/13/18, 9:48 PM
```

Answer (score 1):

Raatty in the Flutter discord server found that Flutter only supports 64 bit iOS devices

```
Make sure your simulator is using a 64-bit device (iPhone 5s or later) by checking the settings in the simulator’s Hardware > Device menu.
```

Source:

https://flutter.io/setup-macos/